# How to create a custom function similar to string.split() to reverse a string

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I'm trying to write a function on which if we pass the string like we do for split, it returns a string which is reversed -

This is what I've tried -

```
var abc = "hello"
var result;
String.prototype.reverser = function(str){
  var temparr = str.split('').reverse().join('');
  return temparr;
}
result = abc.reverser();
console.log(result);
```

I'm expecting olleh but rather getting -

VM1179:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at String.reverser (:4:19)
    at :7:14

Comment: You didn't pass a string into `reverser`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a parameter `str`. The string is already binded to the method on prototype. Just use `this` to access the string.

```js
var abc = "hello"
var result;
String.prototype.reverser = function(){
  return this.split('').reverse().join('');
}
result = abc.reverser();
console.log(result);
```

**Note:** You shouldn't directly add enumerable properties to `prototype`. Instead use `Object.defineProperty()`

```js
var abc = "hello";
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype,'reverser',{
  value:function(){
    return this.split('').reverse().join('');
  }
})
var result = abc.reverser();
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! any documentation or website i can use to read more about this?

Comment: This would be a good teaching moment for using `Object.defineProperty` rather than creating enumerable properties on built-in prototypes, which is a Bad Idea™. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have added that. I can guess why its bad for Objects and Arrays. But what can be side effect for Strings?

Comment: Thanks guys! I found this post on why its a bad idea for anyone reading up on this like me - 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice

Comment: @MaheerAli - You never know when someone will have an actual String object (not primitive) lying around and decide to use a `for-in` loop on it. :-) People do very funny things...

Comment: (BTW, just FWIW, to match the way standard methods are defined, you'd want `writable: true` and `configurable: true` in that `defineProperty` options object.)

Answer (score 0):

When extending `String.prototype` with your `reverser()` function, the string with the new method on it can be accessed with `this`; the way you have defined it expects an argument `(str)`, that isn't provided. See how `this` can be used to access the string in this working snip:

```js
var abc = "hello"
var anotherStr = "what do you know?"
var result;
var anotherResult;

String.prototype.reverser = function(){
  var temparr = this.split('').reverse().join('');
  return temparr;
};

result = abc.reverser();
anotherResult = anotherStr.reverser();

console.log(result);
console.log(anotherResult);
```